# Applying "simultanious" multiple conditions on a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to apply multiple rules on a numpy array:
Say I have a numpy array of `x = [0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7]` and I want to convert all the values smaller than 0.2 to 0, all the values between 0.2 and 0.55 to 1 and all the values bigger than 0.55 to 2. Naturally I can't use

```
    x[x < 0.2] = 0
    x[x >= 0.2] = 1
    x[x > 0.55] = 2
```

because the third line will convert all of the "zeros" into "ones", and then all of the "ones" into "twos".
I am positive that there is a smarter and easier way to do so, but unfortunately I couldn't find it.

Thanks

Comment: `np.digitize` is your friend.

Comment: Or you could precompute the masks.

Comment: Smarter way is definitely `np.digitize`. The following works just in this case. `a[a<0.2] = 0, a[np.logical_and(a>=0.2, a<0.55)] = -1, a[a >= 0.55] = -2, a *= -1`.